# Why can't change color of string resulting from script?

Tags: html, css, styles

I don't konw how to change the color of this string to white. I barely handle PHP and HTML so the Script is beyond me. I'm not quite sure how you format the text resulting from it. I just want it to be white.

This is the code:

```
<div style="font-size: large; float:right; color: white; display:inline; padding: 14px;">
<script language="javascript">
document.write('<a href="?s=' + geoip_city() + '">¿Estás en ' + geoip_city() +'?</a>');
</script>
</div>
```

Also just in case you want to check it out this is where i'm testing it, it's at the far right of the menu.

http://chusmix.com/

Anyway, It maybe a really stupid question with an obvious answer (I hope so). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at FireBug, it looks like _yellow.css and style.css are both overriding the style that would be inherited by the parent `div`'s inline style.  You could add a class for this link:

```
.white-link {
    color:white;
}
```

and then update your script:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write('<a class="white-link" href="?s=' + geoip_city() + '">¿Estás en ' + geoip_city() +'?</a>');
</script>
```

OR define the style inline, as you've done with the div:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write('<a style="color:white" href="?s=' + geoip_city() + '">¿Estás en ' + geoip_city() +'?</a>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you probably have other CSS rules that set the links' colors.
It works with normal text: http://jsbin.com/equxa4

Consider a CSS solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="City">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.City {font-size: large; float:right; color: white; display:inline; padding: 14px;}
.City a {color:white;}
```

You may have to set the different states of the link, depending on your CSS:

```
.City a:link, .City a:visited, .City a:active, .City a:hover {color:white;}
```